# How to print return value of javascript function in HTML "The addition of{x} +{y}={result}"?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print out the result of x+y in HTML now it only show me the result but I wanted to be like: 
The addition of{x1} +{y}={result} ??? :/

```html
<html>
  <body>
    
    <br/>
    Enter first number:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1">
    Enter second number:
    <input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2">
    <p>Click the button to calculate x.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
       var result;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
        if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)){
         result="enter number!"
         }
   else{ 
          result = +x + +y;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too trivial and any programming enthusiast or professional would know how to perform string concatenation.

Comment: `result = x + ' + ' + y + ' = ' + (+x + +y);`

Comment: @Mabast, [It's the truth because you didn't do enough research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261725/497418). You can choose to feel offended that I didn't just spoon-feed you an answer, or you can learn from your mistake and attempt to learn how to behave as a productive member of the [SO] community.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    
    <br/>
    Enter first number:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1">
    Enter second number:
    <input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2">
    <p>Click the button to calculate x.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
       var result;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
        if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)){
         result="enter number!"
         }
   else{ 
          result = +x + +y;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The addition of " + x + " and " + y + " is " + result;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a string which contains your variables:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + ' + ' + y + ' = ' + result;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it.